# How to build a roc curve and do statistical analysis for discrete classifiers?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, roc, computational-statistics

I have 5 supervised databases containing S similar documents and N not similar. Within each base, I separated 10 samples with bootstrapping. These samples contain the identifier of each document. For each document in the database, I retrieve the S documents that contain the largest similarity values ​​according to some measure of similarity between strings (so the similarity measure is my binary classifier). Since I have several measures of similarity between strings, I would like to test which one is best.

Dataset 1
Sample 1
Document 1 - TP: 2125, TN: 3, FN: 2, FP: 1
...
Document X - ...

Sample 2
...

Dataset 2
Sample 1
Document 1 - TP: 658, TN: 48, FN: 1, FP: 1

...

Within the S documents, if document X is really similar to the document I am testing, I increment the value of "true positives", otherwise I increase the value of "false positives".

In the end, I have a confusion matrix for each element of the sample. And with that, I get a single confusion matrix, averaging all samples.
I would also like to make the average confusion matrix of all bases. Can I do this since the size of each base is different?

My question is whether I can make the ROC curve having only a single final confusion matrix, starting from the point (0,0) and going to the point (1,1). And if I may, what is the best statistical test for AUC since I am averaging the matrices of confusion.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You'll need to edit your question to add some context & detail before this can be answered. What's are "the databases"? What role is bootstrapping playing? What hypothesis do you want to test? What classification method are you using? It may help to review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic - "The ROC curve is created by plotting the true positive rate (TPR) against the false positive rate (FPR) at various threshold settings" - what's the threshold in your case?

Answer (score 1):

By the time you get to the confusion matrix, it's already too late for ROC analysis. ROC analysis works on a continuous score. When you retrieve the S closest documents, instead of directly calling a positive/negative label, you need to calculate a score (e.g., closer to 1 would mean positive and closer to 0 would mean negative). That can then go to your ROC analysis.